# How is this SQL leading to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sql

Here's a snippet of my PHP that is creating the table:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table.' (
                `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                `name` VARCHAR( 55 ) NOT NULL ,
                `venue` VARCHAR( 55 ) NOT NULL ,
                `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
                `desc` TEXT NOT NULL
                )';
```

This is making the `time` column become the current timestamp when I add or change a row. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the default behavior of the `TIMESTAMP` column type. I'd recommend changing it to a `DATETIME` column.

You can also alter the behavior by explicitly specifying how you want it to behave.

```
added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The above column specification will not have the `ON UPDATE` behavior. You can also specify a `NULL` value or 0 as the default.